# How can I concatenate two dates as strings in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a date field and i need to display the week of the date field in select statement,

Eg : if the date is '2014-09-15 00:00:00', i need to display as '2014-09-14 to 2014-09-20 ' which is start day to end day of the week

I have tried using

```
   Select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1)+' to ' +DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7)
```

But it is giving me conversion failure,how can i write the above to display in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these expressions

`dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1)`

and

`DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7)`

returns a `Datetime` value and `' to '` is a `string` value.

You will need to convert your datetime values to a string to concatenate these values together.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1), 121) 
       + ' to ' +
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7), 121)

RESULT:  2014-09-14 00:00:00.000 to 2014-09-21 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast you statement 
like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1), 25) + ' to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7), 25)
```